# How to hide any div on a webpage by adding a specified parameter at the end of url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I am a blogger and I am currently learning html. So I don't have much knowledge  about javascript. Now I want to know how to hide any div in a web page by adding a parameter like this. **Means if I added `?hide=header-wrapper` at the end of my url, it should hide the header-wrapper**. Can I do this with javascript?

I want the correct code to do this please. And I want to know how to make the code auto detect the div and  hide it as much as I do `?hide=divID` in the  url.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: you should look about the css display:none and create a js to reveal it on whatever action you want. but I do'n understant why you want this oon your URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this too.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var hide_id= getParameterByName('hide');


       /*just pass the name of query string parameter that you want to hide like
 in your url (`?hide=header-wrapper`) id that you want to hide is `header-wrapper`and query
 string parametername is `hide` so use getParameterByName('hide') */

if (hide_id) {
        $('#'+hide_id).hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: just pass the name of query string parameter name that you wish to hide in function `getParameterByName()`

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried a lot to do this. Now it works. Thank you very much PHP Worm

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var toHide = getUrlParameter('hide');

    if (toHide) {
        $('#' + toHide).hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: As I told you I am just learning HTML and don't know Javascript a lot, Can you please describe what those code pieces does?

Comment: `toHide` is `id` of `element` so you must do this to hide the `id`  `$("#"+toHide).hide();`

Comment: @PHPWorm... Then, Won't it auto detect the `id` just by adding it as parameter?

Comment: no by default it will treat `toHide` as an `html tag` `like div, img, p, a`